# Hide Custom menu background Image on specific pages

Tags: wordpress, menu, background-image, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to implement something like this where the menu has a background image(Check this to understand https://bellacures.com/)

I couldn't find a way to do it so I insert image behind the menu using css(Here is the site I am working on http://www.nailarcade.com

```
.fw-header .fw-header-main {
   background-image: url("http://www.nailarcade.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Nail-Arcade-Website-Slide-2.jpg");
         background-size: cover;
}
.fw-header .fw-header-main 
{
    height: 900px;
}
```

The problem now is I want the image to appear only on the homepage
How can I hide it from other pages?

or is there any other better way to implement the menu image background

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@earid

your reply was helpful

But this later work for me

```
.home .fw-header .fw-header-main {
   background-image: url("http://www.nailarcade.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Nail-Arcade-Website-Slide-2.jpg");
         background-size: cover;
         height: 900px;
}
```